# Unable to get dynamic Meta tags in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, meta-tags

I am working on codeigniter and i am trying to use dynamic meta tag but meta tags not working for me, Here is my code in controller

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(2);
        $data['id'] = $id;
        $data['metas'] = array(
             array('name'=>'description', 'content'=>'A short but sweet DEFAULT description of this fine site'),
             array('name' =>'keywords', 'content'=>'some awesome DEFAULT keywords for those rascally web crawlers')
            );
```

Here is my view

```
<?php 
      foreach($metas as $meta)
      {?>
         <meta name="<?=$meta['name']?>" content="<?=$meta['content']?>" />
<?php }?>
```

Comment: how is it not working? What happens if you var_dump the $metas in your view?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What actually happens? Errors? No generated HTML? How are you passing the `$data` array to the view? Are you passing it to the correct view?

Comment: where did you defined $metas? is it $data['metas']?

Comment: @Mehrdad: means i want whenever i copy url then new meta data( which is coming from controller) and then paste ...then new title , description, image should be display

Comment: As folks already mentioned, use `var_dump($metas);` in your view. This way you can check if `$metas` array is correctly passed to the view.  If you wont be able to figure this out, update your question and include the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

Just go inside codeigniter 3 system/helpers/html_helper.php and copy the function and put it in your own libraries

```
function meta($name = '', $content = '', $type = 'name', $newline = "\n")
{
    // Since we allow the data to be passes as a string, a simple array
    // or a multidimensional one, we need to do a little prepping.
    if ( ! is_array($name))
    {
        $name = array(array('name' => $name, 'content' => $content, 'type' => $type, 'newline' => $newline));
    }
    elseif (isset($name['name']))
    {
        // Turn single array into multidimensional
        $name = array($name);
    }

    $str = '';
    foreach ($name as $meta)
    {
        $type       = (isset($meta['type']) && $meta['type'] !== 'name')    ? 'http-equiv' : 'name';
        $name       = isset($meta['name'])                  ? $meta['name'] : '';
        $content    = isset($meta['content'])               ? $meta['content'] : '';
        $newline    = isset($meta['newline'])               ? $meta['newline'] : "\n";

        $str .= '<meta '.$type.'="'.$name.'" content="'.$content.'" />'.$newline;
    }

    return $str;
}
```